# Is there a way to tell when I receive an ajax request with node/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, fs

I'm running a node/express server that sends the ajax-start.html file. The ajax-start.html files has a script in it that makes ajax requests to the server. All that works fine. However when the server receives an ajax request I want to be able to modify the text file before sending it. (I'm very new to this, and trying to modify an example from MDN to fit my needs.)

The HTML (ajax-start.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Ajax starting point</title>

    <style>
      html,
      pre {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      body {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
      }

      pre {
        line-height: 1.5;
        letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color: white;
      }

      label {
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 33px;
      }

      select {
        width: 350px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Ajax starting point</h1>

    <form>
      <label for="verse-choose">Choose a verse</label>
      <select id="verse-choose" name="verse-choose">
        <option>Verse 1</option>
        <option>Verse 2</option>
        <option>Verse 3</option>
        <option>Verse 4</option>
      </select>
    </form>

    <h2>The Conqueror Worm, <em>Edgar Allen Poe, 1843</em></h2>

    <pre></pre>

    <script>
      const verseChoose = document.querySelector("select");
      const poemDisplay = document.querySelector("pre");

      verseChoose.onchange = function () {
        const verse = verseChoose.value;
        updateDisplay(verse);
      };

      function updateDisplay(verse) {
        verse = verse.replace(" ", "");
        verse = verse.toLowerCase();
        let fname = verse + ".txt";
        let url = `textFiles/${fname}`;

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url);
        request.responseType = "text";

        request.onload = function () {
          poemDisplay.textContent = request.response;
        };
        request.send();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The node/express(app.js)

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(`assets`));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/ajax-start.html");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`listening`);
});
```

Comment: You can check the `X-Requested-With` header. It will be `XMLHttpRequest` for AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar — That's a non-standard header that only *some* third-party Ajax libraries add.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish AJAX? Just use different endpoints for them.

Comment: "*All that works fine*" - where is the `textFiles/` endpoint? Are these files currently served by `express.static`?

Comment: @Barmar ---- The idea was if I could tell that the request was an ajax I could modify the files before sending them via AJAX.

Comment: @Bergi yes the `textFiles/` are being served by `express.static`, there is not an endpoint for the `textFiles/`.

Comment: @UnderwaterBaker Add one. Then each time, read the file from the assets directory, and modify the text before sending it. (Or does "modify the text file" actually refer to rewriting the stored file on the disk?)

Comment: @Bergi I'm referring to rewriting the text file on the disk.

Comment: @UnderwaterBaker Ah. Then you should not use a `GET` request for that. (Unless it's something like counting views). Use a `POST` request instead, make a separate endpoint for that which modifies the file, then sends the updated contents or redirects to the GET url

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to detect Ajax requests per se, but HTTP has a number of options for providing different versions of content.

If you want to provide the same data in a different format (it is quite common to e.g. HTML for a direct request and JSON for an Ajax request) then you can make use of the [`Accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) (with your server-side code defaulting to HTML unless the `Accept` header (available via `req.headers`) expresses a preference for JSON).

If you want to provide subtly different content then you can use a query string (`req.query`) on the URL.

Significantly different content is generally better off with a different endpoint entirely.

You can also make use of the `X-Requested-With`, which is non-standard, but you can add it (like an `Accept` header) with `setRequestHeader` as that is a common pattern for expressing "This is Ajax". It does avoid standard approaches though, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Even while the question title asks to "*tell when I receive an ajax request*", the OP's actual problem is "*I want to be able to modify the text file before sending it*".

Comment: @Bergi — They said they wanted to do that, but the stated problem is detecting the Ajax request … with modifying the text file is presumably the thing they plan to do once that problem is solved (and about which they've provided no details so would be impossible to answer anyway).